# PHP Round function - round up to 2 dp?

Tags: php, math, rounding

In PHP how would i round up the value 22.04496 so that it becomes 22.05? It seems that
    round(22.04496,2) = 22.04. Should it not be 22.05??

Thanks in advance

Comment: It only considers the digit after `4` (which is also `4`) then `22.04` is correct. It is not rounding first 96 to 100 and then 45 to 50.

Comment: `Should it not be 22.05??` not really? 044 rounds down to 04, 046 would round up to 05, works as designed

Comment: 22.04496 is closer to 22.04 than to 22.05. Look for yourself: `22.04496 - 22.04 = 0.00496` but `22.04496 - 22.05 = -0.00504`

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/, IMO

Comment: Basically i need to get the same result as given in js by this function:
    
    function roundNumber(num, dec) {
 var result = Math.round( Math.round( 
    num * Math.pow( 10, dec + 2 ) ) 
    / Math.pow( 10, 2 ) ) / Math.pow(10, dec);
 return result;
}

Answer (score 8):

you can do it using ceil and multiplying and dividing by a power of 10.

```
echo ceil( 1.012345 * 1000)/1000;

1.013
```

Comment: This is more elegant than my solution which was just to add .05 to the original number and still use the round method i.e. round(#.####+0.05, 2)

Comment: So, 1.012345 rounds up to 1.013 ? how ?
1.012345
1.01235
1.0124

Comment: This method is flawed: `ceil(77.4 * 100) / 100 === 77.41`.

Comment: The multiplication and dividing number is `pow(10, $dp)` where `$dp` is the number of decimal places you want to round up to. That may be useful to know for rounding to an arbitrary number of decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Do not do multiplication inside a ceil, floor or round function! You'll get floating point errors and it can be extremely unpredictable. To avoid this do:

```
function ceiling($value, $precision = 0) {
    $offset = 0.5;
    if ($precision !== 0)
        $offset /= pow(10, $precision);
    $final = round($value + $offset, $precision, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    return ($final == -0 ? 0 : $final);
}
```

For example `ceiling(2.2200001, 2)` will give `2.23`.

Based on comments I've also added my *floor* function as this has similar problems:

```
function flooring($value, $precision = 0) {
    $offset = -0.5;
    if ($precision !== 0)
        $offset /= pow(10, $precision);
    $final = round($value + $offset, $precision, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return ($final == -0 ? 0 : $final);
}
```

Comment: Finally! Thanks for a correct implementation of such a function.

Comment: Give this man a medal. Been looking all day for a solution that doesn't break with weird floating points. With slight modification, also makes a good function for finding floor() with precision. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @LorienBrune I added my Floor function too.

Answer (score 2):

The round function of PHP can handle an additional argument, which controls how the rounding is done: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Examples from the link:

```
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);   // 10
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 9
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 10
echo round(9.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);  // 9
```

Comment: Note that this does require PHP 5.3

Comment: This doesn't make a difference for this case: 
`php > echo round(22.04496, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);`
`22.04`
`php > echo round(22.04496, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);`
`22.04`

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way:

```
echo ceil(round($value * 100)) / 100;
```

Example:

```
$value = 77.4;
echo ceil($value * 100) / 100; // 77.41 - WRONG!
echo ceil(round($value * 100)) / 100; // 77.4 - OK!
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working well.

```
round(1.211,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); 
// Res: 1.21
```

My Solution:

```
$number = 1.211;

echo myCeil($number,2);

function myCeil($number,$precision = 0){
    $pow = pow(10,$precision);
    $res = (int)($number * $pow) / $pow;
    
    if($number > $res){
        $res += 1 / $pow;
    }
    return $res;
}
// Res 1.22
```

Answer (score -3):

Why should it be `22.05`? The third decimal is *less than 5*, hence when you round it to 2 decimal precision it's rounded down to `22.04`

Comment: why is this an answer ?