# Rounding up to the second decimal place

Tags: php, numbers, rounding, ceil

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Round function - round up to 2 dp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426799/php-round-function-round-up-to-2-dp)

What my problem is:

When i use

```
ceil(3.6451895227869);
```

i get like

```
4
```

but i want

```
3.65
```

Can you help me out?

```
UPDATE
```

Please remember:
This should always round to ceil like while rounding

**3.6333333333333**

it must not be **3.63** but should be **3.64**

Comment: That's not what `ceil` does: "Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.". You'll need a different method

Comment: please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=round+to+precision+php did help solve your problem

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following post about rounding numbers up  to a number of decimal positions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074527/php-rounding-numbers

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

```
<?php

echo round(3.6451895227869, 2);

?>
```

**EDIT**
Try using this custom function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#102641

```
<?php 
function round_up ( $value, $precision ) { 
    $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
    return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; 
} 

echo round_up(3.63333333333, 2);  // 3.64

?>
```

Comment: No, but i want it ceil. This gonna round it off..
ok, lets see for example: 

i want to ceil this number:
3.63333333333
to
3.64

Comment: You don't need a custom function - you can use the flag `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`, as per my answer

Comment: It won't work as desired. Try number 3.6333333333333...

Comment: The PHP round + PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP will only round up if the last digit is 5 or more. Example: 3.444 will become 3.44.
So the function sent by tomexx is actually really cool and works perfectly. I just tested it here.

Comment: This function is not really the best. It could be much simpler. Like in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074527/php-rounding-numbers/2074540#2074540

Comment: @tomexx, on php 5.3 your function could produce wrong results. See sandbox [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e403c61a1d270ada6063bb3f59a63a2e5a6890fd)

Comment: Do not do multiplication inside a ceil function! You'll get floating point errors and it can be extremely unpredictable! Try round_up(2.22, 2) and you'll see it gives an answer of 2.23 due to floating point errors, whereas round_up(2.21, 2) correctly gives 2.21. To avoid this do: `function ceiling($value, $precision = 0) {
  $offset = 0.5;
  if ($precision !== 0)
   $offset /= pow(10, $precision);
  return round($value + $offset, $precision, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
 }`

Comment: `In PHP 5.6 onwards, you may prefer to use the ** operator.` (instead of  `pow()`)

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48456940/1245149

Comment: Tomexx, may the Holy Grand Sacrificied Mina bless you and your family for this wise answer!

Answer (score 7):

You want round

```
round(3.6451895227869, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

The second argument is the precision, the flag tells `round` to always round up (like `ceil`)

Comment: The PHP round + PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP will only round up if the last digit is 5 or more.
Example:
3.444 becomes 3.44. 
3.445 becomes 3.45

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

So the function sent by tomexx is actually really cool and works perfectly. I just tested it here.

<?php 
function round_up ( $value, $precision ) { 
    $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
    return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; 
} 

echo round_up(3.63333333333, 2);  // 3.64

?>

Comment: Just a note: This solution no longer answers the question since it has been edited.