# PHP round three decimal places up with problem

Tags: php

Thank you if you help me to solve this.
I need this round up with 2 decimal

```
<? echo round(ceil((0.55*100))/100,2); // output 0.56 ?>
```

I want this

0.050 -> 0.05

0.051 -> 0.06

0.055 -> 0.06

0.059 -> 0.06

0.060 -> 0.06

Thank you!

Comment: `round(ceil((0.55*100))/100,1);` this?

Comment: I wonder why `ceil()` doesn't provide a `precision` argument like `round()` oO

Comment: Also [PHP Round function - round up to 2 dp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426799/php-round-function-round-up-to-2-dp)

Comment: See the [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function: `<? echo round(0.55, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // output 0.55 ?>`.

Comment: I just finished answering your question when I discovered that people had hastily closed your question and I got a phone call at the same time. Does the above comment help?

Comment: All replies is incorrect. Please validate values

Comment: Help please. Thank you

Comment: Your code seems to work for all of the examples you provided. `$num = .052;
$round = round(ceil(($num*100))/100,2);
echo $num.' rounded to '.$round;` outputs `0.052 rounded to 0.06`. All of your examples to the hundredths place work as expected. Are you looking for a function that will round `.55` to `.6` AND `.055` to `.06`?

Comment: WOUNDEDStevenJones it works... but try with $num = 0.55

Comment: Unclear, your rather minimal code example doesn't match the output values required; 0.55 or 0.055?